# How can i ntop install skip or auto input using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

`aptitude update && sudo aptitude install ntop -y`
I using this to install ntop, how can i skip package configuration?[image]

[something like that](https://youtu.be/zGDp6EzmaQ8?t=31)